# How to get the content section to top?

Tags: html, css

I try to layout my html page and get the content section to the right at top.

With:

**float: right;** >> the content section moves to the right, but not at top of the page.

**float: top;** >> the content section moves back to the left.

See screenshot for illustration!

[image]

```css
    form.contact{
      margin: 1% 1.5%;
      padding: 5px;
      border-style: solid;
      width: 37.5%;
      hight: auto;
    }
    #content{
      float: right;
      padding: 10px;
      border:1px solid red;
      width: 50%;
      hight: auto;
    }
    form {
      float: left;
      margin: 1% 1.5%;
      width: 63%;
    }
    nav{
      float: left;
      margin: 0 1.5%;
      width: 63%;
    }
    footer{
      float: left;
      margin: 1% 1.5%;
      width: 37.5%;
      border-style: solid;
    }
```

```html
        <form class="contact">
          <label>Contact</label></br></br>
          First name:
          <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Your name please?">
          <br><br>
          Email:
          <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Your email please?">
          <br><br>
          <input type="submit" value="Press the button">
        </form>
        <nav>
           <a href = #>Just Me</a><br>
           <a href = #>Portfolio</a>
        </nav>
        <section id = "content"><h2><strong>Content section</strong></h2></section>
        <footer>
          <label>Socializing</label>
        </footer>
```

Comment: In HTML what comes first in code, comes higher in page. then why do you put content at the bottom if should come at the top?

Comment: I recommend you try to avoid using `float` and `position: absolute` to do layout, as neither is meant for that. It will only give you a lot of troubles along the road.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding position to the `div#content` can also make the content go right....

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}
form.contact {
  margin: 1% 1.5%;
  padding: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  width: 37.5%;
  hight: auto;
}
#content {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 50%;
}
form {
  float: left;
  margin: 1% 1.5%;
  width: 63%;
}
nav {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1.5%;
  width: 63%;
}
footer {
  float: left;
  margin: 1% 1.5%;
  width: 37.5%;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="contact">
    <label>Contact</label>
    </br>
    </br>
    First name:
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Your name please?">
    <br>
    <br>Email:
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Your email please?">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Press the button">
  </form>
  <nav>
    <a href=#>Just Me</a>
    <br>
    <a href=#>Portfolio</a>
  </nav>
  <section id="content">
    <h2><strong>Content section</strong></h2>
  </section>
  <footer>
    <label>Socializing</label>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response, your explanation and the right answer.

Comment: You are Welcome .if the above snippet is working for you then you can accept my answer...

Answer (score 2):

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <section id="content" style="float:right;"><h2><strong>Content section</strong></h2></section>
    <form class="contact">
      <label>Contact</label></br></br>
      First name:
      <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Your name please?">
      <br><br>
      Email:
      <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Your email please?">
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Press the button">
    </form>
    <nav>
       <a href = #>Just Me</a><br>
       <a href = #>Portfolio</a>
    </nav>
    <footer>
      <label>Socializing</label>
    </footer>
  </body>
 </body>
</html>
```

Shift the content section above the form and add float right for the type of visual effect you want.

This would effectively align the content section to the right and since it would be above other content, it will be automatically be on the top right.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response, your explanation and the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
<section id = "content"><h2><strong>Content section</strong></h2></section>
    <nav>
       <a href = #>Just Me</a><br>
       <a href = #>Portfolio</a>
    </nav>
```

Interchanging `section` and `nav` will also solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response, your explanation and the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please put your content section above your form and set css for content `float:right;`
 and this will put your content to right and the form below this will be shifted above.

Answer (score 1):

you may also use `flex` (while grid starts to show up) and `order` to .. reorder your grid :)

example:

```css
/* FLEX UPDATE*/
body {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  }
#content{
  order:-1;
  }
form {
  order:-2
    }
/*END  FLEX UPDATE*/
form.contact {
  margin: 1% 1.5%;
  padding: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  width: 37.5%;
  hight: auto;
}
#content {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50%;
  hight: auto;
}
form {
  float: left;
  margin: 1% 1.5%;
  width: 63%;
}
nav {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1.5%;
  width: 63%;
}
footer {
  float: left;
  margin: 1% 1.5%;
  width: 37.5%;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<form class="contact">
  <label>Contact</label>
  </br>
  </br>
  First name:
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Your name please?">
  <br>
  <br>Email:
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Your email please?">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Press the button">
</form>
<nav>
  <a href=#>Just Me</a>
  <br>
  <a href=#>Portfolio</a>
</nav>
<section id="content">
  <h2><strong>Content section</strong></h2>
</section>
<footer>
  <label>Socializing</label>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

it is very important to position the elements inside html code.here your problem can be  simply solved by change the position of your **section#content** to just below of **form#contact** on top of the nav.

```css
form.contact{
  margin: 1% 1.5%;
  padding: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  width: 37.5%;
  height: auto;
  float:left;
}
#content{
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  border:1px solid red;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}
form {
  float: left;
  margin: 1% 1.5%;
  width: 63%;
}
nav{
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1.5%;
  width: 63%;
}
footer{
  float: left;
  margin: 1% 1.5%;
  width: 37.5%;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form class="contact">
      <label>Contact</label><br/><br/>
      First name:
      <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Your name please?">
      <br><br>
      Email:
      <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Your email please?">
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Press the button">
    </form>
   <section id = "content"><h2><strong>Content section</strong></h2></section>
    <nav>
       <a href = #>Just Me</a><br>
       <a href = #>Portfolio</a>
    </nav>
   
    <footer>
      <label>Socializing</label>
    </footer>
  </body>
 </body>
</html>
```